# Conversion of 16 Byte Array Response to Decimal

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working on an application in which I received a 16 byte array response. In that response there will be 1 bit set to indicate a position value. For example I may get:

**0000 01000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000**

Which would represent that **device #5** has responded (first bit represents device #0).

Is there a simple way to get convert a byte array of this length to it's decimal value?

Comment: how did you get 5 from your provided sequence?

Comment: only one bit will be set to 1 or could be multiple bits?

Comment: What do these 4-char groups represent? a byte? (BTW: why is the second group 5-chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decimal` class is not an appropriate way to represent such data. What you're probably looking for is [`BitArray` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can use a for-loop and the counter would be your device number.

**Edit: Added Code Sample**

```
int n = 0;

// Loop trough the byte array.
for(n = 0; n < bytearray.Length; n++)
{
   // Exit the loop as soon as the indexed byte from the array is 1.
   if(bytearray[n] != null && bytearray[n] == 1)
   {
      break;
   }
}

// Here you can string your device name together.
string deviceName = "device #" + n;
```

*Remark:* Actually I don't understand your example.  Why do you say 16 bytes, but each group apprears to be of 4 bits. How did you get the device number 5 from that bytearray?

Comment: (EDITED) What is the type of your `bytearray` if both `bytearray[n] != null` and `bytearray[n] == 1` are meaningful? Do you get a warning about the `!= null` criterion always being met?

Comment: I haven't tested this code. If it doesn't work as `byte[]` array, it would be an integer (which you would have to convert first). It is just an example of how I would try to deal with it. I'm not completely sure how he stores the values tho.

Comment: I am not sure about it either, but I assumed each `byte` in the array could be either zero or one of `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x04`, `0x08`, `0x10`, `0x20`, `0x40`, `0x80`. There is a question on whether each array entry carries one bit or eight bits.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
byte[] yourByteArr = { 0, 0, 32, 0, };

var firstSetBit = (new BitArray(yourByteArr)).Cast<bool>()
    .Select(Tuple.Create<bool, int>).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1);
int indexOfFirstSetBit = firstSetBit != null ? firstSetBit.Item2 : -1;
```

If it could not be that no bits are set, just do:

```
int indexOfFirstSetBit = (new BitArray(yourByteArr)).Cast<bool>()
    .Select(Tuple.Create<bool, int>).First(x => x.Item1).Item2;
```